# Why doesnt the execution wait to the await?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am  trying to open a page in a xamarin forms project in this away:

```
public async Task<string> AbrirPaginaEscaner()
{
    ScannerView miScannerView = new ScannerView();
    ScannerViewModel miScannerViewModel = miScannerView.BindingContext as ScannerViewModel;

    await _navigation.PushModalAsync(miScannerView);

    //await _navigation.PopModalAsync();

    return miScannerViewModel.CodigoQr;
}
```

The new page is opened, but I was expecting that code is not continuing until I close the new page, but the code return the result before the page is close.

Why the code is continuing beyond the await? How could I wait until the second page is close? I have commented the line in which I close the page, becuase if not, I can't see the page opened because it is close immediately.

Thanks.

Comment: because that's not the way it was designed to work, frankly.  The modal page should call Pop when the user is done doing whatever they need to do on the second page - the calling page shouldn't be the one to do it.

Comment: I understand that, but in any case, the real problem is that the second page get information that the first page needs to do its work. If the code continue without waiting the second page is pop, the first page can't do its work. In fact, in any other application, for example in entity framework, if I use await the code wait until the async method finish its work. But in this case the behavior is different, await or not, the code continue and it doesn't give time to second page to get the data. When I use await I expect the code wait until the task that I am waiting is finished.

Comment: you are awaiting the **navigation**, not the **page**.